# Coding a mathematical expression

Tags: r

I am supposed to write a function that, for the values of `Pi` and `P*` returns the α.

[image]

I am having trouble with the usage of sum in my function.

So far I have something like this:

```
sqrt((sum(x[i], i == 1, i == length(pstar)])*(p-pstar)^2)/n)/pstar)*100
```

Comment: `100*sqrt(mean((p - p_star)^2))/p_star`

Answer (score 1):

A sum over a vector `x` in R is just `sum(x)`, not `sum(x[i], i == 1, i == length(x)) * x`. (In fact, the latter doesn’t make much sense even if the syntax was correct, since there’s no multiplication involved in a sum.)

So, in your case:

```
sum((p - pstar) ^ 2)
```